# Why are code snippets unavailable on profiles?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I have a profile. The picture contains a unicorn, and it talks of unicorns, but when I try to insert a snippet of code about unicorns:

> [image]

There is no snippet button:

> [image: User Profile Edit Section; No snippet button]

I also tried to manually add the snippet declaration text as well as the code, but the preview shows no snippets at all; it only shows nothing but plain, boring text with syntax highlighting.
Why is this so?
Is this because of some risk? Is it because that it is unnecessary?
Has it been implemented before?
If so, what has been caused due to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll answer with a simple question:

#### Why???

Or, in more detail: I don't think we should have code snippets available in profiles. There is no good reason to have them except maybe "for fun", which isn't valid for user profiles.

On the sites where snippets are active we can have snippets sandbox in their meta, where anyone can experiment and post fun snippets as much as they want.

Comment: I don't see why a little bit of fun isn't valid for user profiles? Your own profile features an animated gif, that serves no other purpose than a little bit of fun.

Comment: @yannis there is a difference, gif is simple and not distracting too much. The amount of fun it allows is pretty limited. Code snippet can get very heavy and distracting.

Comment: This would depend on the gif. Some are not that simple and can be too distracting. In any case, I'm not arguing for code snippets in user profiles - in fact, if I had a say I'd also remove animated gifs. I just disagree with the "fun isn't valid for user profiles" argument. User profiles have always been the one place where users are allowed to have a bit of fun.

Comment: @yannis bit of fun I agree, might edit my answer after thinking about it some more. :)

Comment: I agree with @yannis, you can only have fun in your profile (excluding the Formatting Sandbox). You can always put the snippet at the bottom, and you can put it in a spoiler.

Comment: My new question is: _**Why not?**_ Why go through all the work of _removing_ code snippets from Markdown _just_ for profiles. The easier way to do it is to _leave it in_ and make your life less complicated. "Why?" isn't really a reason to answer. It is more of an excuse, in this case.